# Android Google Maps: disable dragging in MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, drag, mapfragment

Can I disable drag functionality when the user tries to drag the map with his fingers without   disturbing the Zoom in and Zoom out?

Any one please suggest an idea of doing this!
  Thanks for your Precious help!!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I think here's what you're looking for:

Inside [Google Maps Android v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#scroll_pan_gestures)

> Scroll (pan) gestures
>
> A user can scroll (pan) around the map by dragging the map with their
>   finger. You can disable scrolling by calling
>   UiSettings.setScrollGesturesEnabled(boolean).

Comment: Thanks! That's the great help!!

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Updated link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/controls

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665420/7135685

Answer (score 114):

You can disable dragging in `MapFragment` using:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 16):

for disable dragging in `MapFragment` this code :

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```

works as @tomrozb said.
but it dosn't disable map zoom by touch on map. for that use this code beside above code:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Comment: second 1 about zoom, was usefull. +1

Answer (score 8):

you can use isScrollGesturesEnabled for map

**java:**

`googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false)`;

**kotlin**

```
googleMap?.uiSettings?.isScrollGesturesEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 6):

You can disable dragging in MapFragment using:

```
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabledDuringRotateOrZoom(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to set this in code. You can configure the gestures from XML:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    map:uiScrollGestures="false" />
```

As well as `uiScrollGestures`, you can set `uiZoomGestures`, `uiTiltGestures`, and `uiRotateGestures`.

See [XML Attributes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#using_xml_attributes) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved inside the onMapReady class:

````
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //Hide zoom controls or buttons
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        //Restrict zoom gestures
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
    }```
````