# setClickable api google maps v2 android

Tags: android, api, google-maps, maps

I'm migrating an app developed with google maps api for android v1 to v2. Drawing the map and disable the map to show a route so I disable the touch and zoom to prevent vision loss by myMapView.setClickable (false). I'm trying to do for the v2 but there is no similar method.

I have watched events like setOnCameraChangeListener but without results.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting a reference of the GoogleMap and passing null to its onMapClickListener()?

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with a combination of these 2 methods

[Android Google Maps: disable dragging in MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979550/android-google-maps-disable-dragging-in-mapfragment/16980327#16980327)

[Google Maps Android MapView v2: disable zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878616/google-maps-android-mapview-v2-disable-zooming)