# How to restrict android google map to a city?

Tags: android, google-maps, city

How can i restrict android google map to a city?
I am currently following code for show google map:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

I want to show just a city. Any way?

Comment: this is my problem too ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Google Maps: disable dragging in MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979550/android-google-maps-disable-dragging-in-mapfragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final LatLngBounds DUBAI_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(24.5908366068, 54.84375),
            new LatLng(25.3303729706, 55.6835174561));


map.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(DUBAI_BOUNDS);
```

Comment: How did you get the southwest coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Use official document   [restrict the user's panning to a given area](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#restricting_the_users_panning_to_a_given_area)

To restrict user.

update the dependencies for your Play Services:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

Comment: Hey man thx for answer but i want to user won't to another positions just see for example Adelaide on map and can not move to another places just zoom in and zoom out on Adelaide.

Answer (score 1):

You can [disable scroll gesture](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#scroll_pan_gestures) like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27617407/6950238) answer of [madhu sudhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4264996/madhu-sudhan):

```
mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```

where `mGoogleMap` - object of `GoogleMap` class.